# Nullable shortcut or extension for parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following line of code that I repeat zillion times, and there are similar codes.

```
    public ActionResult View(int ? id)
    { 
        if (id.HasValue == false)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
       .....

    }
```

How can i make this shorter?

Comment: It's 2 lines of code, I don't think reducing that to one line warrants the extra layer of complexion.

Comment: I don't think `HttpNotFound` is the correct status in this case.

Comment: what would be better?

Comment: You can try write action filter as it can short-circuit rendering of the view... Not sure if it will be more compact/readable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an attribute for it. I could look something like this:

**Attribute**

```
public class NullableValidatorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected String[] ParametersNames { get; set; }

    public String HttpNotFoundStatusDescription { get; set; }

    public NullableValidatorAttribute(params String[] parametersNames)
    {
        if (parametersNames == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parametersNames");

        ParametersNames = parametersNames;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var parametersNames = new HashSet<String>(ParametersNames);

        foreach (var parameterName in parametersNames)
        {
            var parameterValue = filterContext.ActionParameters[parameterName];

            if (parameterValue == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult(HttpNotFoundStatusDescription);
                return;
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
[NullableValidator("id", "id2", HttpNotFoundStatusDescription = "some description")]
public ViewResult Test(int? id, int? id2)
{
    return View();
}
```

This above is just a raw implementation. For example, you can remove parameters' names from constructor and resolve on any action parameter (getting parameter type over reflection or something) and so forth.